# How to persist an entity dynamically to different tables?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have an `@Entity` class to persist using `spring-boot`, `hibernate` and `postgres`.

Now I want to dynamically adjust the table where the entity gets saved to (or read from).
Is that possible?

My goal is to create some kind of caching table with large datasets. I want to optimized and refresh the cache once a day (during that procedure, that might last several hours, I want any entity operation to take place on the other table). Then, after the rebuild and optimization finished, I want to switch back to the first table (and use the 2nd table vice versa when rebuilding again).

Is that possible at all?
If not, how could I achieve this?

Comment: It is not possible with JPA. And the design looks very weird. For example what are you going to do with the data saved to the 'other' table during your cache optimization? Why not simple use a cache with write/read through instead

Comment: I could live with that neglecting any changes in the active cache during rebuild of the 2nd. My goal is to keep performance on the cache database as good as possible while rebuilding the 2nd cache (which will include many reads and writes).

Comment: I would really investigate DBMS specific ways of doing what you want to achieve and not want to solve this with JPA. I'm sure the DBMS has table synchronization functionality which can be scheduled.

Comment: The problem is also: the inactive table will/should be updated by a different tool, while the main application operates on the active table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the class like:

```
@Entity
@Table("cache_table_name")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
class CachedVersionOfOriginal extends Original {
 //nothing here
}
```

They will have the same structure and TABLE_PER_CLASS insures two different tables.

If you want to pull Original and then insert to the CachedVersionOfOriginal, you could use the Proxy Pattern like:

```
@Entity
@Table("cache_table_name")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
class CachedVersionOfOriginal extends Original {
 private Original original;
 public CachedVersionOfOriginal(Original original){
   this.original = original;
 }
//Then delegate
@Override
public String getPropertyA(){
  return orginal.getPropertyA();
}

}
```

or use Apache Commons to do Property by Property copy

Comment: So, this could give me two tables, right? And I would then have to create a `DAO-service` and depending which table should be read or write, I have to chose a different dao (and of course the different object) accordingly?

Comment: yes. Actually it's better if you write a single one and then, with generics and maybe two factory methods you instantiate it for each type.